# Copy multiple structs into a buffer using memcpy in c

Tags: c

1. I have several structs (of u8 fields) which I want to convert into a buffer, is this the  best way?

   ```
   struct struct_a a;
   struct struct_b b;
   u8 buffer[64];
   u8 *next_pos;

   os_memcpy(buffer, &a, sizeof(struct_a));

   next_pos = buffer + sizeof(struct_a)/sizeof(u8);

   os_memcpy(next_pos, &b, sizeof(struct_b));
   ```
2. Is this the best way to calculate the overall length of the buffer?

   ```
   buffer_len = (sizeof(struct_a) + sizeof(struct_b) + ... )/sizeof(u8);
   ```

Thanks

Comment: @LihO Are you serious?

Comment: Assuming `u8` is a `typedef` alias for `unsigned char`, its size is going to be 1, making `sizeof(u8)` just a long-winded way of writing `1`. Obviously, dividing by 1 is rarely useful.

Comment: That is dangerous thinking. u8 could be a typedef that is guaranteed to be 8-bits, which unsigned char is not (having the only requirement that it be the smallest unsigned type ***large enough*** to store the basic character set).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Is it? Then how could we have a type that is 8 bits in size, if `unsigned char` is bigger than that? What would `sizeof(u8)` be then?

Comment: @nightcracker2: You are thinking backwards. I was referring to a situation in which unsigned char is < 8-bits. The ASCII character set, for instance, is only 7-bits. There are not a lot of machines with a word size of 7-bits, but it is a possibility. But if the basic character set is not ASCII, then unsigned char could also be 16-bit, so it works both ways; this is in fact the case in languages like Java, where char encodes UTF-16.

Comment: @nightcracker But as `sizeof(unsigned char)` is guaranteed to be `1`, there can be no datatype smaller than that.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman No, both examples are wrong. As glglgl notes (and I was hinting at before), there can be no datatype smaller than `unsigned char`. The standard requires `CHAR_BIT` to be at least 8. Combine this information to see that if `u8` exists, it's guaranteed that `sizeof(u8) == sizeof(unsigned char) == 1`.

Comment: @nightcracker: The C89 spec. guarantees this behavior with respect to the minimum size of CHAR_BIT, but how does that forbid unsigned char from being < 8-bit or on a platform that does not conform to C89 or > 8-bit on any system? There are machines where a byte is smaller than 8-bit, POSIX and C89 do not like it, but they do exist. The whole point was not to assume an integral data type has a fixed-width, which is why assuming that u8 aliases to something is a bad idea. If the system defines a typedef with an explicit size, use it whenever applicable.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Now you're just being ridiculous. How can we even talk about a language if we're not assuming some specification? And besides, the only system I could possibly imagine where you can have a `u8` type where `CHAR_BIT < 256` is a 4-bit system. Now I doubt C will be ever used for that system, if such system even exists.

Comment: @nightcracker: C can and has been used on such systems, and I am not throwing specifications out the window here. Just C89, because C existed for over 20 years before that standard was published. I would not even be adding any input to this discussion if I had not run into this issue on an embedded platform many years ago. Since then, I never make _any_ assumptions about the size of integral types, even if newer language specification versions have clarified. Compilers can provide intrinsic data types with different bit-sizes that are completely unrelated to the C integral types on a platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `u8` means unsigned 8 bits. Hence, `sizeof(u8)` equals 1. So you can simply write:

```
os_memcpy(&buffer[sizeof(struct_a)], &b, sizeof(struct_b));
```

For your second question, except that dividing by 1 is useless, it's a perfectly fine way to compute the len of the buffer.

I'm not a big fan of `buffer + sizeof(struct_a)` but it's also good.

**Edit:** Also, when doing that kind of stuff, if the size of the elements of buffer is not 1, I cast buffer into something with your equivalent of `u8`. This way, I don't have to divide by the size of the elements of buffer.

Comment: Several structs (I have more than 2) might be null hence I prefer using the pos pointer and increment it each time if it isn't null, Thanks!

Comment: @Melody, I've edited my message. I'm not sure to understand your comment but if you have multiple structs to copy, you may have a cleaner code with a pos pointer. If it's what you're saying, I fully agree.

Answer (score 0):

Define a buffer either this way,

```
#define MAXBUF (999)
type struct 
{
    int size; //or short, or char, or long long, depending on size...
    char buffer[MAXBUF];
} buffer_t;
```

Or, this way, and allocate enough space (enough defined to be how much you need),

```
#define MAXBUF (999)
type struct 
{
    int size;
    char buffer[MAXBUF];
} buffer_t;
```

Then a function to add stuff to the buffer,

```
int
buffer_add(buffer_t* buffer,void* thing,int len)
{
    if(!thing) return 0;
    if(len<1) return 0;
    memcpy( &(buffer[buffer->size]),thing,len);
    return(buffer->size+=len);
}
```

Now, using it is easy,

```
typedef char u8;
struct struct_a { u8  x[100]; };
struct struct_b { int y[25]; };

int main()
{
    u8 buffer[64];
    u8 *next_pos;

    buffer_t mybuffer;
    buffer_add(&mybuffer,&a,sizeof(a));
    buffer_add(&mybuffer,&b,sizeof(b));
    buffer_add(&mybuffer,&buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    buffer_add(&mybuffer,next_pos,sizeof(*next_pos));
    //do stuff with mybuffer
}
```

Comment: What's with the `return(buffer->size += len)` statement? Shouldn't just be `return(buffer->size + len)`?

Comment: How big is buffer->size?  You just added len bytes to it.  Wouldn't you want to increase the size?